# Create a telerik MVC grid in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I've been trying to figure out how to create a telerik MVC grid in codebehind? The telerik docs have a way of doing it with RadGrid but not their MVC Grid control..

What I'm basically trying to do is create a grid based on some conditions, like I may have a grid like this:

```
 Html.Telerik().Grid<ZeDate>("dates")
        .Name("MyGrid")
        .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(10))
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .ColumnContextMenu()
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.id))
        .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
        {
            dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("_SelectAjaxEditing", "Dates")
            .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "Dates")
            .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "Dates")
            .Delete("_DeleteAjaxEditing", "Dates");
        })
        .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.name);
            columns.Bound(o => o.date1);
            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text);
                commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage);
            }).Width(185);
        })
        .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InForm))
        .Render();
```

But I might in some cases want to not show a specific column such as 'date1' or I might not want to allow the grid to be filterable, basically stuff like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the "no code-behind" that Mystere Man mentioned, there are several different ways to do conditional aspects in an MVC view with Telerik.  Since Telerik uses a fluent interface you can set it to a variable and take advantage of that.  So for example you could do:

```
var telerik = Html.Telerik().Grid<ZeDate>("dates")
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.name);

        // Only render the date column if the designated
        if (Model.CanSeeDate)
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.date1);
        }
    });

// Only let the grid be filterable if allowed
if (Model.GridFilterable)
{
    telerik = telerik.Filterable();
}

// Perform other telerik setup
telerik.Render();
```

Answer (score 2):

MVC doesn't have code behinds.  Well, that's not entirely true, you can use a code-behind in WebForms views, but that's a side-effect of using the WebForms engine and its use is strongly discouraged.

In any event, you would only use a code-behind when you need to use a webforms server control.  Since MVC controls don't use the WebForms page lifecycle, code-behinds have no use for them.

Perhaps you can explain what it is you're trying to do.

EDIT:

Based on your changes, I still don't understand.  You can do all that in the view, you don't need a code behind.  What is your reason for using a code behind?

Comment: How can I do that based on conditions?

Comment: @meds - by putting the conditions in your view.  KallDrexx gave you an example, you can do similar things for column creation, or anything else.